# Trying to detect when a user is at 100 messages, then resets, and adds one to caseCount, but it doesn't work, and I get no error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is using MongoDB in Discord.js, all this code is in the message Event

So in MongoDB, I'm trying do see if somebody has 100 or more message, then if they do, it resets their messageCount, and adds one to "caseCount" the messageCount, this is what I have so far, but it doesn't work, nor does it give me an error:

```
if(profileData.messageCount >= 100) {
        await Profiles.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            userID: message.author.id,
          },
          {
            $inc: {
              messageCount: 0,
              caseCount: + 1
            }
          }
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single query i.e.,:

1. Check if `messages` array is >= 100.
2. Increment `caseCount` and reset `messageCount`.

```js
await Profiles.updateMany(
    {
        $expr: {
            $gte: [{ $size: "$messages" }, 100]
        }
    },
    {
        $set: { messageCount: 0 },
        $inc: { caseCount: 1 }
    }
);
```

**Note**: Also check if you have those two fields in your `Profile` schema

Comment: I tried it, but when the user has 100 messages, it does nothing for some reason. I get no error as well

Comment: Are those two fields in the schema?

Comment: messageCount and caseCount, yes

Comment: message.author.id is an object. I just tried using the updated code, and still nothing. I'm, not sure why

Comment: One last point is if you are using `findOneAndUpdate` you need to pass option `new` as `true` to get the updated document as response. Check this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: I used your code instead of findOneAndUpdate

Answer (score 1):

`$inc` in MongoDB increases or adds a certain value to a document's property. What you're currently doing with `messageCount` is you're adding 0 to it, keeping it at the same amount. I believe what you're looking for is the `$set` keyword that sets a property to a desired value.

```js
if (profileData.messageCount >= 100) {
    await Profiles.findOneAndUpdate({
        userID: message.author.id,
    }, {
        $set: {
            messageCount: 0
        }
        $inc: {
            caseCount: 1
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but for some reason, it doesn't reset or add one to caseCount

Comment: Have you done so with or without the `+` sign?

Comment: Like when increase "caseCount: + 1"?

Comment: yeah. Try doing it without the `+` sign.

Comment: What is `caseCount`'s current value?